# linkedin v2 api: combine projection and decoration

Tags: linkedin-api

Using Postman, I can query the endpoint to retrieve comments on a share:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:share:myshare/comments?count=35
```

and we have a response like

```
{
  "paging": {
    "count": 10,
    "start": 0
  },
  "elements": [
    {
      "actor": "urn:li:person:x",
      "created": {
        "actor": "urn:li:person:x",
        "time": 1472051509000
      },
      "commentsSummary": {
        "totalFirstLevelComments": 2,
        "aggregatedTotalComments": 2,
        "selectedComments": [
          "urn:li:comment:(urn:li:activity:x,x)",
          "urn:li:comment:(urn:li:activity:x,x)"
        ]
      },
      "id": "x",
      "lastModified": {
        "actor": "urn:li:person:x",
        "time": 1472051509000
      },
      "message": {
        "attributes": [

        ],
        "text": "This is a comment"
      },
      "object": "urn:li:share:x"
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought I'd be able to use a request like:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:share:myshare/comments?count=35&projection=(actor~)
```

or maybe

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:share:myshare/comments?count=35&fields=actor,id,message,created,lastModified,object&projection=(actor~)
```

But these both return `200 OK` with `{}` in the body... Wat.

The docs are woefully out-of-date *and* light on details and examples. They don't even mention whether (or how) to combine projection and decoration.

How can I get `actor` information "decorated" into the comment objects so I don't have to issue additional requests to fetch it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:share:777777777/comments?count=35&projection=(elements*(*,actor~,created(*,actor~),lastModified(*,actor~)))
```